# What is the guideline on when you can and cannot use lazy entrypoints, and are there any limitations to using them?

Tags: bigmap, performance, entrypoint, lazy-entrypoint

My current understanding is that lazy entrypoints are stored in big_maps which impacts gas and improves performance of operations inside the entrypoint.

I also understand that there are limitations to big_maps - they are not directly comparable, they cannot be pushed or packed, you cannot iterate on them or know their lengths, and they cannot contain other big_maps.

How do these big_map limitations impact operations contained inside the lazy entrypoints?

Are there operations that you cannot perform or types that you cannot access or process inside a lazy entrypoint, and how do you know when to select a lazy entrypoint instead of a regular entrypoint?

Comment: Do you know the article [Understand your Bigmap](https://www.marigold.dev/post/understand-your-bigmap) from Marigold? Could be maybe helpful for your question.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; when an entrypoint is big: lazy is a good option. When a contract is trivial, lazy is not a good option. When you want to be able to upgrade a contract, lazy is a good solution.

> How do these big_map limitations impact operations contained inside
> the lazy entrypoints?

Big map does not limit the entrypoint operations in any way.

> Are there operations that you cannot perform or types that you cannot access or process inside a lazy entrypoint

There is nothing that you can do in entrypoints that you cannot do in lazy entrypoints.

> How do you know when to select a lazy entrypoint instead of a regular
> entrypoint?

A drawback of lazy entrypoints is that you pay the bigmap access cost when you call it. This cost is payed one for each call. On contrary, with non-lazy entrypoints, you pay a cost for the loading of the whole contract. So **if you have a big non-lazy entrypoint, you increase the gas of each call even for calls of another entrypoint**.

For each entrypoint *e*, you have to measure how much it costs to call *e* if it's lazy VS non-lazy and how much it costs to call another entrypoint if *e* is lazy VS *e* non-lazy. And choose depending on how often the entrypoint is expected to be called.

Exemple: a big entrypoint that is called rarely can be set lazy without any problem.

Notice that the new cache system complexifies the reasoning because the answer may differ when the contract is in the cache VS when it's not (so it depends on the contract's usage).